# Javascript Timeout function with Google Maps API Polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am currently trying to create a program that increases the opacity of a polygon every 2 seconds until its non-transparent. I eventually want to do this with multiple polygons to relay data to the user over time, but I am simply trying to get one polygon to work. The code is written in `Javascript` and uses the timeout function to do so.

The code is supposed to draw a red square one the map with opacity 0.1, then 2 seconds later draw a similar square with opacity at 0.2. This process goes on until the opacity is equal to 1. The problem is that the program skips the first 9 squares (where opacity < 1) and draws the final square (opacity = 1). I believe that there may be a problem with how I am doing my delay.

Below is my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
            #tabs{
                width: 100%;
            }      
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>      
        <script>
        function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 11,
                center: {lat: 33.678, lng: -116.243},
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            });
            for(i = 0.1; i < 1; i+=0.1){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: '#FF0000',
                        fillOpacity: i,
                        map: map,
                        bounds: {
                        north: 33.685,
                        south: 33.671,
                        east: -116.234,
                        west: -116.251
                        }
                    });
                }, 1000+i*20000)
            }
        }
        </script> 
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified your code and implemented it with setInterval() function. Also please note that there is no need to create new instance of polygon inside a loop, you can just change polygon options.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 11,
            center: {lat: 33.678, lng: -116.243},
            mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });
        var m_opacity = 0.1;
        var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: m_opacity,
          map: map,
          bounds: {
            north: 33.685,
            south: 33.671,
            east: -116.234,
            west: -116.251
          }
        });
        var m_timer = window.setInterval(function(){
          m_opacity += 0.1;
          if (m_opacity <= 1.0) {
            rectangle.setOptions({
              fillOpacity: m_opacity
            });
          }  
          if (m_opacity === 1.0) {
            window.clearInterval(m_timer);
          }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

```css
#map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #tabs{
            width: 100%;
        }      
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&v=3&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

You can see this sample on jsbin as well: http://jsbin.com/yepagec/edit?html,output